# Different inertia values even with random_state set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

Im trying to make my algorithm, which involves KMeans, reproducible, but even If I set random_state value I always get different inertia values.
I'm using this [page](https://github.com/danielgribel/hg-means/blob/master/data/page.txt) dataset without the first line (dataset size).

**Steps/Code to Reproduce**

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

points = np.genfromtxt('page.txt')
for l in range(10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=30, n_init=1, random_state=42)
    kmeans.fit(points)

    centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    print('{0:.20f}'.format(kmeans.inertia_))
```

**Expected Results**

I expect to get printed ten time the same value

**Actual Results**

```
1008436173.14048004150390625000
1008436173.14048004150390625000
1008436173.14047992229461669922
1008436173.14048004150390625000
1008436173.14047992229461669922
1008436173.14048004150390625000
1008436173.14047992229461669922
1008436173.14048004150390625000
1008436173.14048004150390625000
1008436173.14048004150390625000
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code on Google Colaboratory with the dataset you provided (the first line is removed). The outputs are shown exact same results 10 times

#### Environment

```bash
Python 3.7.13

numpy                         1.21.6
scikit-learn                  1.0.2
```

#### Output

```
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
1008436173.14048218727111816406
```

Comment: Yes, I previously tested it on google collaboratory too and It works also for me, but it still doesn't work on my computer

Comment: Can you specify your local environment?

Comment: macOS-12.4-arm64-arm-64bit

Comment: I've tried it on my machine (macOS-12.4, chip: M1 pro, Python 3.9.12). It's worked perfectly.